# What does this mantra Om Ah Hum Sarba Amrita Siddhi Hum Dze mean?

Tags: mahayana, mantra, meal-gatha

This is some sort of meal gatha.

> ОМ А ХУМ САРБА АМРИТА СИДДХИ ХУМ ДЗА
>   Om Ah Hum Sarba Amrita Siddhi Hum Dze

I'm stumped on translating it.

[Source](http://vbuddisme.ru/forum/forum1/topic76/).

Comment: The source says this mantra transmutes food into _amrita_ -- the nectar of health and longevity. What are you doing on russian Buddhist sites?!

Comment: I'm teaching my toddler Russian- we do shrine maintenance (подношения), I wanted to add a meal gatha to the repertoire of practices. Meditation and philosophy won't come for years.

Comment: Morphologically Russian is an interesting language. I get lots of insights into Pali/Sanskrit thanks to the common roots. (In that sense you might as well have him learn Hindi...) Let me know if you have any questions on the language, perhaps via G+, I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I think Mantras like this require initiation to use, and plus mantras can't really be given a translation. I think you'd be better off translating a traditional set of verses rather than a mantra for something to teach your child.

Answer (score 2):

Mantras aren't complete sentences, so you can't really translate them, but the individual syllables usually have standard symbolic meanings, but there are always multiple layers of meanings in any given mantra, but here goes:

The first part, Om Ah Hum, is a very important set of syllables. Om represents the enlightened body of a Buddha, Ah represents the enlightened speech of a Buddha, and Hum represents the enlightened mind of a Buddha. Om is very commonly used to begin a Mantra and Hum is often used near the end of a Mantra, like in the famous Mantra for Avalokiteshvara, **Om** Mani Peme **Hum**.

Sarba I assume is a derivation from the Sanskrit word Sarva, which means all or every, and Amrita means nectar, so Sarba Amrita means all nectar.

Siddhi is a term that can refer to attaining magical powers through meditation, but I think it can also be used as a general term for spiritual attainments in general.

Hum is again, the representation of the enlightened mind of a Buddha, and as previously stated, it is often used near the end of a mantra.

I don't know the meaning of Dza however.